# Can the order of pages for "multiple pages per sheet" be changed?

Tags: microsoft-word, printing

I'm using Word 2013's feature to print multiple pages per sheet. I want the pages to be placed on a sheet ordered in columns / vertically instead of per rows / horizontally. That is, Word does this by default:

[image: Horizontal ordering]

But I would like my pages to be ordered on sheets like this:

[image: Vertical ordering]

To clarify, this is the option I'm using:

[image: Word printer options]

I'm happy to use a workaround, because normally the "horizontal" ordering is fine; I just want it different for this one time. I can utilize the printer driver options too (HP LaserJet 500 Color M551 or PDFCreator) but haven't found any way to bend those to my needs either.

One workaround that will *not* work unfortunately, is rearranging the page content, because that would muck up the page numbering.

Two final other things to note that are important: I want to print two-sided (though a manual printer feed step is okay), and I have a rather large document (about 50 pages)

Comment: I'm not sure about doing this natively in Word.  I believe you can do that with third-party software.  When I used Windows, I used a program called [Clickbook](http://www.bluesquirrel.com/products/clickbook/).  It gives you great flexibility in resequencing and resizing pages to fit different formats and arrangements.  It's a paid product, but they have a free trial so you could evaluate whether it's worth it for you (or accomplish your one job).

Comment: Thanks @fixer1234, that figures. Turned out Adobe Reader actually also has a "Page Order" setting in the print dialog, I've posted it as an answer should it help anyone else stumbling on my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not long after posting my question have I found the answer myself. As mentioned in the question, workarounds are acceptable, plus I already have PDFCreator. All you need in addition is Adobe Reader (I've got version 11), which has a Print Dialog that gives a "**Page Order**" option for exactly this.

First, you should print from Word to PDFCreator with a simple 1 page per sheet setting.

Second, use Adobe Reader to print the PDF with Multiple Pages per sheet and "Vertical" page ordering, like so:

[image: annotated Adobe Printer dialog]

In the screenshot I'm printing yet again to PDFCreator, but you can also choose your actual laser/inkjet printer there.

Answer (score 2):

This function depends on the printer and driver capabilities. For most printers this setting is changed via the `Printer Properties`.

[image]

When you choose this option you can select <kbd>Advanced...</kbd> to open Advanced Options.

Under `Document Options` you can adjust the `Pages per Sheet Layout:` to your liking.

[image]